# SlideUp not firing after first time triggered on tabbing module

Tags: javascript, jquery, modularity, slideup, tabbing

I have a tabbing module that I'm beginning to modularise. The basic functionality is working but the slideUp function doesn't seem to be firing after the first time it is triggered. Instead tabs are just laying over the top of one another.

```js
(function() {


  var tabbing = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.el = $('.js-tab-panels');
      this.tabs = this.el.find('.js-tabs');
      this.navItem = this.tabs.find('.nav-item');
      this.panel = this.navItem.closest(this.el);
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.navItem.on('click', this.toggleActive.bind(this));
    },
    toggleActive: function(el) {
      this.panel.find('.js-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
      var add = $(el.target).closest(this.navItem);
      add.addClass('active');

      this.hidePanel();
    },
    hidePanel: function() {
      this.panel.find('.panel.active').slideUp(300, this.showPanel());

    },
    showPanel: function() {
      var panelToShow = this.panel.find('.js-tabs li.active').attr('rel');
      this.panel.find('.panel.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#' + panelToShow).slideDown(300, function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    }


  };

  tabbing.init();

})()
```

```css
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.tab-panels ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab-panels ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-panels ul li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}

.tab-panels ul li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
}

.tab-panels .panel {
  display: none;
  background: #c9c9c9;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.tab-panels .panel.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-tab-panels tab-panels">
  <ul class="js-tabs tabs">
    <li rel="panel1" class="nav-item active">panel1</li>
    <li rel="panel2" class="nav-item">panel2</li>
    <li rel="panel3" class="nav-item">panel3</li>
    <li rel="panel4" class="nav-item">panel4</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="panel1" class="panel active">
    content1<br/> content1
    <br/> content1
    <br/> content1
    <br/> content1
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    content2<br/> content2
    <br/> content2
    <br/> content2
    <br/> content2
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    content3<br/> content3
    <br/> content3
    <br/> content3
    <br/> content3
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="panel4" class="panel">
    content4<br/> content4
    <br/> content4
    <br/> content4
    <br/> content4
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet here.

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan I can't see your snippet...

Comment: Aha understanding you. I'm v new to posting here. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `hidePanel` function when you call `.slideUp(300, this.showPanel());` you are passing the result of `this.showPanel()` as the second argument of `slideUp` function, but what you want is to execute `this.showPanel` as the callback when `slideUp` animation is complete.

So **to fix that** you just need to pass in a copy of the `showPanel` function as the second argument instead of its result:

```
...slideUp(300, this.showPanel.bind(this));
```

Comment: Amazing. Worked like a charm. I can understand now why it was working once but not again because I was passing the result. I still don't fully understand how Binding this works though. Thank you.

Comment: The `.bind(this)` call just creates a copy of the function with a custom value  for the `this` keyword inside the function that's being copied. That lets you use `var tabbing` as the value for `this` instead of the callback function scope. As for the callback as the second argument, it just expect a function to be executed when the animation is done and that's why we pass in a copy of the function we want to call. Mark it as the correct answer if this was helpful for you :)